# Entity Framework code-first error when using stored procedure with fields that have default value

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I need to insert an entity by calling a stored procedure. The table in the database has a column called `CreateDateTime` that has a default value of `GetDate()`.

I do not let the stored procedure set / update the `CreateDateTime` column.

When I call the `dbcontext.SaveChanges()` it does indeed call my stored procedure and it inserts a row but then EF throws the following error:

> A function mapping specifies a result column 'CreateDateTime' that the result set does not contain.

My `DbContext` class has the following:

```
modelBuilder  
    .Entity<Test>()  
    .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>  
        s.Update(u => u.HasName("TestUpdate"))  
        .Delete(d => d.HasName("TestDelete"))  
        .Insert(i => i.HasName("TestInsert")));
```

The `TestInsert` stored procedure is a simple `INSERT INTO... SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

On my `Test` class I have a property like the following.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: does your table contains CreateDateTime ?

Comment: Your final select must contain a projection of your CreationDateTime instead of just SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: @SilentTremor Yes the table contains a CreateDateTime and the "default" value is "GetDate()".

Comment: @CodeNotFound The stored procedure returns SCOPE_IDENTITY() and I don't see any examples of of using projection when using MapToStoredProcedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @CodeNotFound suggestion.
The return from the TestInsert stored procedure must return the entire result set and not just the SCOPE_IDENTITY()
Not only that but the stored procedure must contain a parameter for each "mapped" field in the entity model.

My last line it the InsertTest stored procedure looks something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```